# "Error starting replication" in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I am creating a "pull" replicator document in couchdb 1.1.0:

```
curl -X PUT http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/_replicator/maintenance -d '
{
    "_id": "maintenance",
    "source":  "http://other.host:5984/maintenance",
    "target":  "maintenance",
    "create_target":  true
}'
```

Now I check the replication state:

```
curl -X GET http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/_replicator/maintenance
{"_id":"maintenance","_rev":"2-0f25f80a2726640944d527d6035e5b80","source":"http://other.host:5984/","target":"maintenance","create_target":true,"_replication_state":"error","_replication_state_time":"2011-09-06T02:35:10+02:00","_replication_id":"354746bf47831195261bf54f3cb6136b"}
```

Something is going wrong, but I do not know what. I have even created the database manually, but it is still not working. Any ideas on where the problem could be?

Comment: Can you see the log file for your database?

Comment: Does the "source" have any admin account?

Comment: @Marcello: yes, it could be, but why should that be relevant? This is a pull replication: it is only reading from the source.

Comment: It says something like: `[Tue, 06 Sep 2011 10:09:01 GMT] [error] [<0.15455.8>] Error starting replication '79db9d1b523640ee78372225e063795e+create_target' (document 'maintenance'): {unauthorized, <<"unauthorized to access database maintenance">>}. Retrying in 160 seconds?`. But I am creating the replication document with the admin user, and the maintenance database has been created locally also with the same user. Why should there be any permission issues? How can I debug this?

Comment: As pointed out by [Robert Newson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314053/error-starting-replication-in-couchdb/7319590#7319590), you probably need to add user credentials to the "source" URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was using the wrong url to start the replication. Instead of

```
curl -X PUT http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/_replicator/maintenance
```

I must do:

```
curl -X POST http://admin:pass@localhost:5984/_replicate -H ...
```

Now the replication starts as expected. It can even be triggered with create_target and continuous, and it works fine.

I still have some problems though: how can I list the active replications? They are not listed in `localhost:5984/_replicator` and the url `localhost:5984/_replicate` only acepts POST requests. How can I cancel a continuous replication?

And finally: what is the purpose of having two different URLs, one `localhost:5984/_replicate` and one `localhost:5984/_replicator`?

Answer (score 2):

The source attribute is wrong, you have to add the remote database:

```
"source":  "http://other.host:5984/maintenance"
```

should work!

Cheers, Bernhard

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted badly. My original command has the database name in the source too. I correct now my original posting.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to authenticate at other.host (it may have require_valid_user=true, for example) so;

```
"source":"http://user:pass@other.host:5984/maintenance"
```

You will likely wish to lock down access to the _replicator db as any reader of the database can see that password (use the _security document to lock it down).

Tightening this up is an active topic of discussion for future releases of CouchDB.

Comment: thanks for the tips. It makes quite sense what you are propossing, but I am still having no luck with the setup. I see this error in the log: `[Mon, 12 Sep 2011 16:45:05 GMT] [error] [<0.4323.3>] Error starting replication '045020f93f9da91e1e6b609754b32a15+create_target' (document 'maintenance'): {unauthorized, <<"unauthorized to access database maintenance">>}. Retrying in 160 seconds`. The database is present in the host where I am replicating to.

Answer (score 0):

**_replicator** is the new format used to remember your replications after a CouchDB restart. If using this format, you can cancel replications by simply deleting the replication document.

https://gist.github.com/832610

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error:

> [Mon, 12 Sep 2011 16:45:05 GMT] [error] [<0.4323.3>] Error starting replication '045020f93f9da91e1e6b609754b32a15+create_target' (document 'maintenance'): {unauthorized, <<"unauthorized to access database maintenance">>}. Retrying in 160 seconds

The actual issue is I was specifying create_target: true in the JSON, yet the database already existed. I believe previously create_target was safe to use if the target already existed, but not in the _replicator/ model.